# What resources are available to learn how to create an app in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Im a noob when it comes to Android Studio and would like to know any websites or books that would help me get started. I know some of the basics but get stuck on moving from one activity to another. I've searched online and even tried youtube with no luck. At this point I don't mind paying for some online courses.

Answer (score 0):

I used YouTube alot for a 2d side stroller paymon wang-lotfi has a great engine.  theNewBoston was also has some great tutorials and ThechernoProject is good for Java game programming.

Comment: Thanks for the info I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

The new boston is good as far as learning the very basics for free. But the best that I've found are on Udacity, although not all of their courses are free. So if you really want to understand your code with project-based learning, I would recommend Udacity, as long as you are willing to pay a bit (Although their free courses are still good).

Comment: I've heard of udacity but never checked it out. I'll go on the site today. Thanks :)